# Get last value from a certain group (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have something like this

```
    Date  Group ID
    11/01 'A'   1
    12/01 'A'   2
    13/01 'B'   3
    14/01 'B'   4
```

What i basically want is to get for example the latest from group 'A'

```
    Date  Group ID LatestID_from_GROUP_A_ordered_by_recent_date
    11/01 'A'   1  2
    12/01 'A'   2  2
    13/01 'B'   3  2
    14/01 'B'   4  2
```

or at least something like this

```
    Date  Group ID LatestID_from_GROUP_A_ordered_by_recent_date
    11/01 'A'   1  null
    12/01 'A'   2  null
    13/01 'B'   3  2
    14/01 'B'   4  2
```

Comment: Sorry it's basically the Latest ID from group A which is 2 (it doesn't neccesarily the highest I want to be the latest date, since 12/01 is the latest basically)

Comment: @savemenico . . . Your data is unclear.  Do you want the latest id overall or the latest as of the date in the row.

Comment: What happens if you add a row with `15/01 'A' 5` ?Do all the rows get '5' as the latest value, or do the first four still get '2'? (Which is basically what Gordon is asking...)

Comment: Yes, and lets say I had only IDs 3 4 and 5 with dates 11 12 and 13 and I add a row with id 1 and date 15 i would still want ID 1 with date 15

Comment: Please edit your question to show more examples, covering all the scenarios you can think of and what should be shown (and the logic involved)..

Comment: Agree, add more example data. Words are easily misinterpreted, examples covering all the corner cases can be crystal clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon was almost there.

You want to create a window over your whole query, but only pick the biggest value of 'A':

```
select 
  t.*,
  max(case when group = 'A' then id end) over (partition by 1) as latest_from_a
from t
```

'partition by 1' will create a window of your complete result set because it only groups by a single static value: 1.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
with demo (somedate, somegroup, id) as
       ( select date '2018-01-11', 'A', 1 from dual union all
         select date '2018-01-12', 'A', 2 from dual union all
         select date '2018-01-13', 'B', 3 from dual union all
         select date '2018-01-14', 'B', 4 from dual union all
         select date '2018-01-15', 'A', 5 from dual  -- example from comments
       )
select somedate, somegroup, id
     , ( select max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by somedate)
         from   demo
         where  somegroup = 'A' ) as last_a
from   demo;

SOMEDATE    SOMEGROUP         ID     LAST_A
----------- --------- ---------- ----------
11/01/2018  A                  1          5
12/01/2018  A                  2          5
13/01/2018  B                  3          5
14/01/2018  B                  4          5
15/01/2018  A                  5          5
```

Note the `max(id)` is only a tiebreaker in the event of multiple rows with the last date.

Answer (score 0):

The logic seems to be:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when group = 'A' then id end) over (order by date) as latest_from_a
from t;
```

The above gets the cumulative maximum up to each date.  If you want the overall maximum:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when group = 'A' then id end) over () as latest_from_a
from t;
```

Comment: Actually no since they 1 and 2 might be flipped over but I still want the one  with date 12/01